# Generate as many documents as cell value

Tags: vba, pdf

I have a label generator code, to generate pdf's, but I need to generate **as many "labels" inside one pdf file** as "packets" in the variable qtypackets exists.

So here is the code, how I can do this? I have an idea with a "for each" but don't know too good, how to implement it inside the code.

```
Sub LabelGenerator()

Dim invoiceRng As Range
Dim pdfile As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFileExists As String
Dim tracking As Range
Dim GoogleBook As Workbook
Dim strtrackingnumber As String
Dim Thisbook As Workbook
Dim displaylabels As String

' -- Setting and open the information book from Gsheet

Set GoogleBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\peter\OneDrive\Escritorio\B2GO\Excels\GoogleConnection.xlsx")

' -- Refreshing the book

GoogleBook.RefreshAll

' -- Select the right sheet

Worksheets("Planilla Envios").Select

' -- Starting the Loop

For Each tracking In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)


' -- Validation

    If tracking <> "" Then
    
    If IsNumeric(tracking) = True Then
    
    
        ' -- Mandatory ID
        
                trackingnumber = tracking.Value
    
                strFileName = "C:\Users\peter\OneDrive\Escritorio\B2GO\Excels\Generated Labels" & "\" & "Label " & trackingnumber & ".pdf"
        strFile = Dir(strFileName)
        
        If strFile = "" Then
        
        ' -- Searching the data variables

        idcompany = tracking.Offset(0, 2).Value
        idcustomer = tracking.Offset(0, 12).Value
        companyname = tracking.Offset(0, 3).Value
        companycontact = tracking.Offset(0, 4).Value
        companystreetaddress = tracking.Offset(0, 5).Value
        companystreetnumberaddress = tracking.Offset(0, 6).Value
        companycommuneaddress = tracking.Offset(0, 7).Value
        companyhousedepartment = tracking.Offset(0, 8).Value
        companyphone = tracking.Offset(0, 9).Value
        companyemail = tracking.Offset(0, 10).Value
        qtypackets = tracking.Offset(0, 11).Value
        customername = tracking.Offset(0, 13).Value
        customerstreetaddress = tracking.Offset(0, 14).Value
        customerstreetnumberaddress = tracking.Offset(0, 15).Value
        customercommuneaddress = tracking.Offset(0, 16).Value
        customerhousedepartment = tracking.Offset(0, 17).Value
        customerphone = tracking.Offset(0, 19).Value
        customeremail = tracking.Offset(0, 20).Value
        reference = tracking.Offset(0, 18).Value
        rate = tracking.Offset(0, 21).Value
        
            ' -- Select the right book to place the data
            
            Set Thisbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\peter\OneDrive\Escritorio\B2GO\Excels\New Shipment And Labels.xlsm")
            Worksheets("Label format").Select
            
            ' -- placing the data in each cell
            
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("D6").Value = companyname
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("D7").Value = companycontact
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("D8").Value = companyphone
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("D10").Value = customername
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("D11").Value = idcustomer
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("D12").Value = customerphone
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("I6").Value = rate
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("I7").Value = "NORM"
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("H11").Value = "1 de " & qtypackets
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("C17").Value = customerstreetaddress
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("H17").Value = customerstreetnumberaddress
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("C21").Value = customercommuneaddress
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("F21").Value = customerhousedepartment
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("H21").Value = reference
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("C25").Value = trackingnumber
            
            ' -- Setting range to be printed
            
            Set invoiceRng = Range("A1:J31")
            
            ' -- setting file name with a time stamp.
            
            pdfile = "Label " & trackingnumber & ".pdf"
            
            ' -- setting the fulli qualified name. The resultent pdf will be saved where the main file exists.
            
            invoiceRng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="C:\Users\peter\OneDrive\Escritorio\B2GO\Excels\Generated labels" & "\" & pdfile, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
            
            ' -- Cleaning up the label format
            
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("D6").Value = ""
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("D7").Value = ""
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("D8").Value = ""
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("D10").Value = ""
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("D11").Value = ""
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("D12").Value = ""
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("I6").Value = ""
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("I7").Value = ""
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("H11").Value = ""
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("C17").Value = ""
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("H17").Value = ""
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("C21").Value = ""
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("F21").Value = ""
            Worksheets("Label format").Range("H21").Value = ""
            
            ' -- end
            
                Worksheets("New request").Select
            
        End If
        
End If
End If
Next tracking End Sub
```

Here are an image example of what Im trying to do.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there only a single label template set up on  the "Label format" sheet?  You would need to either replicate that so you have multiple areas on that one sheet (with page breaks set appropriately) or create multiple copies of that sheet, each with one label.  That's the only way you'd get all the labels in a single PDF file.

Comment: Yes, there is a sheet with the template, I just fill it automatically with the information of each row, for example.

Comment: But there's only one template on the sheet?  What's the maximum number of labels per file?  Is each label printed on a separate page, or can (eg) two labels fit on one page?

Comment: Yes, just one, should I create more?, the maximun of number could be 50 for example.

Comment: Can you share a copy of the "Label format" worksheet ?